# xb_stream_read_chunk(): wrong chunk magic at offset 0x0

Tags: mysql-5.5, mariadb, percona, percona-tools, backup, xtrabackup

I have taken a backup of mysql instance like this

`innobackupex \
   --user=$MYUSER \
   --password=$MYPASS \
   --no-timestamp \
   --parallel=$DUMP_THREADS \
   --stream=xbstream \
   --slave-info \
   --extra-lsndir=$LSN_DIR \
   --tmpdir=$TMP_DIR \
   --no-lock \
   --safe-slave-backup`

I am trying to restore this backup like this.

`zcat backup_file.xbs.gz 2>/dev/null | xbstream -x -C /var/lib/mysql/`

I am getting this following error.

`xb_stream_read_chunk(): wrong chunk magic at offset 0x0.`

I have tried all google suggestions, upgraded xtrabackup to the latest version.

Nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Would have preferred to answer using a comment, but I haven't enough points yet.
Disclosure: I work for Percona. I have put your question to our tech team, and they are not sure that you have created a xstream archive.

[There are examples here](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/innobackupex/streaming_backups_innobackupex.html#examples-using-xbstream)

For xstream the backup would be something like this:

innobackupex --stream=xbstream /root/backup/ > /root/backup/backup.xbstream

and then the extract from backup.xtream would be something like this:

xbstream -x <  backup.xbstream -C /root/backup/

If you need more discussion, that might be easier via the free [Percona forum](https://www.percona.com/forums/) .